Probability of spinner sums equaling $6$
Consider an experiment of simultaneously spinning 3 spinners. Each spinner is equally divided into 6 numbered sections, 1 through 6.
What percent of time will the sum equal 6?

I've tried listing out all possible combinations of the spinner numbers, but that is an infeasible strategy. I am truly stumped on what to do next or how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

How many ways can three ordered natural numbers sum to $6$?

"but that is an infeasible strategy"... not for just $3$ spinners! There are indeed only three (up to reordering): $1 + 1 + 4$, $1 + 2 + 3$, $2 + 2 + 2$.

Presumably, it is infeasible because you want to calculate the same probability for other spinners and goal numbers. The general solution uses either inclusion-exclusion or generating functions.

In thia particular case, you can just use stars-and-bars, and get $\binom 52.$

For the general problem of $~k~$ spinners, each divided into sections representing each element in $~{1,2,\cdots,n},~$ where you want to know the probability that the $~k~$ spinners will sum to $~M,~$ this is a Stars and Bars problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.

Re previous comment, for Stars and Bars problems, where there is (potentially) an upper bound on each variable, and/or a lower bound on each variable, see this answer
for a blueprint of how to combine Inclusion-Exclusion with Stars-And-Bars to
attack this generic type of problem.

In your case, it's easy to least all possible arrangements
$(1,2,3)$, 6 permutations;
$(1,1,4)$, 3 permutations;
$(2,2,2)$, 1 case.
So the probability is
$$
\frac{6+3+1}{6^3}=\frac{5}{108}.
$$
